# GridDB - Force assignment of Master Node on UNSTABLE/WAIT State

Tags: griddb

Since GridDB automatically selects the master node based on performance, does the master node get assigned during the UNSTABLE/WAIT state by analyzing the remaining nodes before more are added and  a quorum is reached?